# WordPress: Force Username to Name and Surname with existing database check

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, registration, hook-wordpress

I have created a website on WordPress where users can register and add various information about themselves. The site has been put together using Elementor, with the WPEverest User Registration form governing the user registration on the front-end.

On registration, I would like to force the username of the new user to be first_name-last_name (I am capturing the fields in the registration form).

But here's the catch: I need to check the existing usernames to ensure there are no usernames that match the new registration. If there are, I would like to append an integer (in sequence) onto the username to differentiate it.

So in other words:

- The first John Smith registers and is assigned a username
  *john-smith*;
- The second John Smith registers and is assigned the username *john-smith-2*;
- The third John Smith registers and is
  assigned the username *john-smith-3*;

I have added the below code, which works on registration, but it also fires when I update a user in the back-end. So if I update the first John Smith, he becomes john-smith-2; stranger, if I update him again he becomes john-smith-2-2.

**I would like this to fire on registration only.**

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

```
 add_filter( 'pre_user_login', 'name_as_username' );
    function name_as_username( $user_login ) {
    
    if(isset($_POST['first_name'])) $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    if(isset($_POST['last_name'])) $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    
    {
        $user_login = $_POST['first_name'].'-'.$_POST['last_name'];
    
    $original_login = $user_login;
    $i = 1;
    
    do {
    //Check in the database here
    $exists = get_user_by( 'login', $user_login ) !== false;
    if($exists) {
        $i++;
        $user_login = $original_login .'-'. $i;
        }
    }  while($exists);
        }
        
    return $user_login;
    }
```

Comment: Here's what the docs say about `pre_user_login`: *This filter is called before the user is created or updated.* Look into the `register_post` action hook.

Comment: `$data = apply_filters( 'wp_pre_insert_user_data', $data, $update, ( $update ? $user_id : null ), $userdata );` - This is the one, where you can check is update or create

Comment: Thanks @ValentinGenev. I've tried substituting in the register_post action hook in and I'm having no luck. In doing so, the username defaults to the prepend of the email address. Sorry if I'm being daft, I am pretty new to PHP.

Comment: @Andrew, you're not being daft at all! The matter is as much PHP as it is WordPress related, so making difference between actions and filter might be the key. I would look into the mentioned difference as well.

Comment: The main thing to look after is that the **filter** let's use read, update and return the user name at a certain step and I'm not sure that's the case with the **action** that I proposed, you can read the user name but mutating it might not be as straight forward.

Comment: Thank you @ValentinGenev. I figured out that a plugin I was using was conflicting with the user_register call. I managed to get it to work with a little help from the plugin developers.

Answer (score 1):

```
function wpcustom_filter_user_data($data, $update, $id) {
    if (!$update) {
        $data['user_login'] = $data['first_name'] . '-' . $data['last_name'];
    }
    return $data;
}

add_filter('wp_pre_insert_user_data', 'wpcustom_filter_user_data', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks @mujuonly! I've tried your code, but the username is no longer forcing to first_name-last_name. Any idea why that would be happening? Where would I input the integer logic in your code above? Sorry, I'm still learning PHP so might be very stupid question.